# In Polyadic Quantificational/Predicate Logic does there exist a mechanical method to determine which invalid sequents will result in an infinite tree?

Tags: logic

Polyadic Quantificational Logic (PQL) is semi-undecidable. What this means for PQL is that there exists no mechanical method that can prove every invalid sequent is invalid. In practice, this means that using the truth tree method, commonly referred to as Analytic Tableaux, will result in infinite trees for some invalid sequents.

My question is - **does there exist a mechanical method to determine which invalid sequents will result in an infinite tree? Is this question decidable?**

So far in my studies it seems like infinite trees are the result of being forced to use universal instantiation before existential instantiation and we could determine which sequents will result in infinite trees by putting premises and negated conclusion in prenex form, conjoining them, then using a **parse tree** to find $\forall x[\exists y[\text{some 2+ place relation}]]$ nodes. Or, possibly, the problem could be side-stepped entirely by adding in an identity component to the appropriate formulas, which would, potentially allow us to use =E and avoid the problem of having to use different names for UIN and EIN. While this feels hacky, identity is being excluded through a quirk of the development rules rather than something inherent to the nature of the sequent - in a way we're just adding it back.

TL;DR - my feeling is that my question is likely to be decidable.